# HTTP GET search form with Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to make a simple search form to filter my list of resources. I've made a form like this, but it's not placing `q` in the url as a query param like I would expect with `method: :get`

```
<%= form_for @conn, post_path(@conn, :index), [as: :search, method: :get], fn f -> %>
  <%= text_input f, :q, placeholder: "Search by title, content, etc." %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit this form with "term" as the search term, it results in `search%5Bq%5D=term` being placed in the url (the url encoded version of the name of the `q` field.) I expected just `q=term`. Am I incorrect in expecting that? What's the proper way to do a simple search form?

Comment: You can either use https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Tag.html#form_tag/2 which would not generate input names for you or simple override the `text_input` name attribute set it to `q`

Comment: Awesome, that worked too. I decided to upgrade to phoenix_html 2.10.5 though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All fields in the form are wrapped by the argument `as`, e.g. `q` with `as: :search` becomes `search[q]`. You can either keep doing this and extract this variable in the controller like this:

```
def index(conn, %{"search" => %{"q" => q}}) do
  ...
end
```

Or, if you want the field to be just `q`, you can upgrade to v2.10.5 of `phoenix_html` and remove the `as` argument. This argument was made optional [just 5 days ago](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/9ee9b846748e9485027337cfa526f79be07ce23e/CHANGELOG.md#v2105-2017-11-08).